# is there any way to hook a debug function into a hook such as init and retrieve every php function whose operates there?

Tags: php, wordpress

is there any way to hook a debug function into a hook such as init and retrieve every php function whose operates there ?

what i meant with PHP function is its name ? is it possible to retrieve any php function name via php built in function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`debug_backtrace()`

PS. http://php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=debug ;)

Comment: wow cool, i thought this is kind of impossible question in php. i have to check this function more. thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

Specifically for Wordpress: [WordPress › wp pear debug « WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-pear-debug/)